# How to use COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI with Full text search column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

How to use 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI' with Full text search column in SQL Server 2008 R2. Select query should show all employees with first name Andres.It should also include names with accent.

Accent Sensitivity option is ON for full text catalogs, it works if i use like operator but doesn't work with contains.

```
select firstName  from Employees 
where firstName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI like '%Andres%'
```

**Results**

```
    Andres
    André
```

**Full Text Search**

```
select firstName  from Employees 
where contains( FirstName , 'Andres')
```

**Results**

```
    Andres
```

I have tried to alter the table and change the column to COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI but no success. (i had to drop the column from catalog first and then alter the column and then rebuild catalog)

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ALTER COLUMN firstname NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Comment: First, what is the problem? What did you expect? Second, you aren't using FTS at all. The `LIKE` operator has nothing to do with full text search. It's just another operator. When used with `%` as a prefix, it forces a scan of the entire table

Comment: Accent sensitivity means that different accents are considered different, yet you expect `CONTAINS` to return both results. In other words, you want the search to be accent-*insensitive*

Comment: What you posted is the correct result if you want accent-sensitive search. Perhaps you are looking for accent-insensitive search instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off accent sensitivity. Unfortunately that is what takes precedence in full-text searches. Collation is not used as you would expect.